# Radio input section toggle with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here is my HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="survey-label">LIFT</td>
        <td data-label="RECOMMEND" class="choice recommended">
            <input name="input_1" type="radio" value="yes" id="c_1_1" data-default="yes">
        </td>
        <td data-label="NOT RECOMMEND" class="choice not-recommended">
            <input name="input_2" type="radio" value="no" id="c_1_2" data-default="no">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="survey-label">WALK</td>
        <td data-label="RECOMMEND" class="choice recommended">
            <input name="input_1" type="radio" value="yes" id="c_2_1" data-default="yes">
        </td>
        <td data-label="NOT RECOMMEND" class="choice not-recommended">
            <input name="input_2" type="radio" value="no" id="c_2_2" data-default="no">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Can I select/deselect the input radios individually by clicking the parent 2nd time?

Here I have done so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var click = $('.choice');
        var input = click.find('input:radio');
        var inputVal = input.val();
        input.attr('data-default', inputVal);
        input.attr('data-alt');

        click.on("click", function() {
        var input = $(this).find('input:radio');    
        var def = input.attr('data-default');
        var alt = input.attr('data-alt');
        (input.val() == def) ? input.val(alt) : input.val(def);
        $(this).toggleClass('none-slected');
        });
    });

</script>
```

I can select/deselect  individual radio, but stuck on choosing a different radio on a table row.

Comment: Note that on an individual table row only one input could be selected.

Comment: do you have any attempts?

Comment: Please post the code that you tried. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262103/how-to-close-please-write-code-type-questions

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$('.choice').on('click', function(e) {
  var row = $(this).parent()
  var radio = $(this).find('input:radio')

  if (e.target == this) {
    radio.prop("checked", !radio.is(':checked'))
  } else {
    if (radio.attr('was-checked') == 'true')
      radio.prop("checked", false)
  }

  row.find('input:radio').attr('was-checked', false)
  row.find('td').removeClass('selected')

  radio.attr('was-checked', radio.is(':checked'))
  if (radio.is(':checked'))
    $(this).addClass('selected')
})
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%
}

.selected {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="survey-label">LIFT</td>
        <td data-label="RECOMMEND" class="choice recommended">
          <input name="input_1" type="radio" value="yes" id="c_1_1" data-default="yes"> Yes
        </td>
        <td data-label="NOT RECOMMEND" class="choice not-recommended">
          <!-- this should be input_1 -->
          <input name="input_1" type="radio" value="no" id="c_1_2" data-default="no"> No
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="survey-label">WALK</td>
        <td data-label="RECOMMEND" class="choice recommended">
          <!-- this should be input_2 -->
          <input name="input_2" type="radio" value="yes" id="c_2_1" data-default="yes"> Yes
        </td>
        <td data-label="NOT RECOMMEND" class="choice not-recommended">
          <input name="input_2" type="radio" value="no" id="c_2_2" data-default="no"> No
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: The solution works, but I need to manipulate the value. The value should be empty or default. So when someone clicks on ".choice" element, the input should be just the default "yes" or "no" (depending on the cell) while adding class "selected" to the element.
If  someone clicks again, "selected" class should be removed and value of input should be empty.
Subsequent clicks will repeat the process.

Comment: if this is in a form, then only the selected radios will be submitted.